# Depth Map resolution shifting

Tags: opengl, shaders, fragment-shader, shadows, shadow-mapping

the problem is with shadow mapping as you can see,

actually it works fine but in a certain condition that the Depth Map size must be equal to the size of rendering buffer, I use an infinite directional light

so if the window is 800x600 the depth map must be 800x600, and when i change the size of the shadow map to be 900x600 it starts to be shifted and when it's size be 1024x1024 it also shifts till it disappears

the GLSL shadow function

```
float calcShadow(sampler2D Dmap, vec4 coor){

vec4 sh = vec4((coor.xyz/coor.w),1);
sh.z *= 0.9;
return step(sh.z,texture2D(Dmap,sh.xy).r);
}
```

here's the result when it's the same size as the window

Colored result & Depth Map
[image: Colored result][image: Depth Map]

and here's the shifted result, as you can notice the depth map is exactly as the previous one with the addition of white space to the right.

Colored result
http://goo.gl/5lYIFV

Depth Map 
http://goo.gl/7320Dd

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a call to [glViewport](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) before rendering to the shadow map. The viewport should be set whenever you render to a render target (or texture) of a different size.

Comment: If it worked, please mark it as accepted.